# How to write a cron expression for a job to run through Mon to Friday at 12:05AM except for if Mon is the second day of the month?

Tags: cron, splunk

I currently have for the first part:

1. Cron expression for job to run from Mon-Fri at 12:05AM
   --> 5 0 * * 1-5
2. Now I want to add the second part of the question to the expression
   (Not to run if Mon was the 2nd day of the month)

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to need to have a pair of schedules - one for days 1,3-31 M-F; and one for day 2 T-F

Comment: Thank you! Let me try that.

Comment: did the pair of schedules work for you?